# Responsive design with different widgets

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I need to create a responsive form using HTMl and CSS. In this form an input field is used to enter the phone country extension. When you click inside the input:

- On desktop: a drop-down attached to the input appears with a search field to filter the possibilities.
- On mobile: a modal covering the whole page appears with the same search field and list of possibilities. A close button is also added to go back to the page.

What is the best way to have the correct widget displayed for the correct device (for example we do not want the modal to appear on desktop)?

Comment: Please take a look at [On-Topic - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi @Trix, I am not sure to understand why my question is not correctly asked? I have added that it is about HTML and CSS but it was already in the tags.

Comment: Questions like, `what is the best way to do something` or `please code this for me`, ... are off-topic. You may show your effort and have clear and exact programming question like, `why this variable does not get value here`. By the way that downvote and close flags are not mine, they are for others. I just put comments on such questions

Comment: Thank you @Trix, this is clear now

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use media queries to denote which functionality should be displayed based on the screen size.

The first step is to create the form layout to be used when viewed on a desktop, and the form layout to be used when viewed on a mobile device.

```
// index.html

// Web Form layout

<form id="web-form">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</form>


// Mobile Form Layout

<div id="mobile-form">
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form id="mobile-form">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With both forms created and declared by an id, we're now going to set the `mobile-form` id to be `display: none`. Only when the device width reaches 768px will we then change this to `display: block` and modify the `web-form` to be `display: none`.

```
// common.css 

#web-form {
  // whatever_styling_you_want
}

#mobile-form {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #web-form {
    display: none;
  }
  #mobile-form {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Using this media query, when a user views your application on a screen size less than 768px in width, the `#web-form` will be hidden while the `#mobile-form` will be displayed. By hiding your modal inside of your `#mobile-form`, it will only be displayed when your `#mobile-form` is displayed.

Comment: Thank you. However I prefer to keep only one form. I just need to have a different widget appearing when the user enter the country phone extension input. But the input itself is the same and so is the form.